# alpha argument for transparency is working only on part of the bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stack, bar-chart, alpha

I have some sample data like this:

```
data <- structure(list(Binomial = c("Herpestes auropunctatus", "Herpestes auropunctatus", 
                                      "Martes martes", "Martes martes", "Mustela erminea", "Mustela erminea", 
                                      "Mustela putorius", "Mustela putorius", "Neovison vison", "Neovison vison"
          ), Introduction = c("Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", 
                              "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", "Successful", "Unsuccessful", 
                              "Successful", "Unsuccessful"), Values = c(7, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4, 
                                                                        0, 112, 9)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to produce a stacked horizontal barplot with bars transparency set to 0.6. I tried this:

```
p <- data %>%
        mutate(Binomial = factor(Binomial, levels = sel_order$Binomial, ordered = T)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(y = reorder(Binomial, Values), x = Values, fill = factor(Introduction)), group = Binomial) +
        geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") + 
        geom_col(width = .6) + 
        scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("#74D055FF","#E55C30FF"), .6)) +
        labs(title = "Points of introductions", fill = "Introduction") +
        xlab("Number of points") +
        ylab("Species") + 
        theme(title = element_text(size = 20,
                                   face = "bold"),
              axis.line = element_line(),
              axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15,
                                         colour = "black"),
              axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13,
                                         face = "italic",
                                         colour="black"),
              axis.ticks.y = element_line(),
              axis.title = element_text(size = 18,
                                        face = "bold"),
              axis.ticks = element_line(),
              panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              panel.background = element_blank(),
              legend.text = element_text(size = 16),
              legend.title = element_text(size = 18),
              plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

But `alpha` is working only on part of the bars:
[image]

I also tried to put `alpha` in other positions (e.g., `ggplot(aes(y = reorder(Binomial, Values), x = Values, fill = alpha(factor(Introduction), .6)), group = Binomial)` or `geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity", alpha = .6)` or `geom_col(alpha = .6, width = .6)`), but nothing works. I am using R 4.2.2. on a Windows 10 x64 machine.

Comment: The issue is that you have two bar layers, i.e. a `geom_bar` and a `geom_col` (with a smaller width of .6). The darker colored part is the part where the two layers overlap.

Comment: That was the problem indeed. Thanks a lot!